# Why does `kill` not appear to be a Bash builtin? (it should be)

Tags: bash, kill, shell-builtin

The Internet is unanimous: `kill` is a Bash builtin. [Bash changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) says the same.

However my other builtins apparently think otherwise:

```
$ builtin kill
bash: builtin: kill: not a shell builtin
$ type kill
kill is /bin/kill
$ command -V kill
kill is /bin/kill
```

This happens even though `help kill` gives documentation and `man bash` mentions `kill` in its “SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS” section (but, if we start to interpret signs, elsewhere in the manual, it is only referred to as “the `kill` *command*”, whereas confirmed builtins are referred to as e.g. “the `wait` builtin”).

What is going on here? Is this part of a plan? I am running Bash 5.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: Which distribution are you running, or is this a home-compiled version of `bash` ?  Or do you have `enable -n kill` in your `.profile` (and related files) that would disable the builtin ?

Comment: Oh you’re right, I have had `enable -n kill` for so long I forgot about it, and about the whole enabling/disabling mechanism. Well this is embarrassing.

Comment: This is a valid question. According to comments, it did not go away on its own. OP responded to a comment, and did something about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kill` is and has always been a built-in utility in `bash` like in was in the Korn shell. It needs to be built-in in order to be able to kill shell jobs (like with `kill %1`) as those job numbers are indexes in an internal table of the shell which an external `kill` could not know anything about.

Built-in utilities may be *disabled* using the `enable` command with its `-n` option.

It is clear [from comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509688/isn-t-kill-a-bash-builtin#comment941916_509688) that you've had

```
enable -n kill
```

in one of your shell's startup files, which disables the built-in variant of the utility and forces the shell to use the external `kill` implementation in `/bin/kill`.

To resolve your issue, remove that command from whatever shell startup file it occurs in.